# PHP rename deletes some of the files?

Tags: php

I have the following photos:

```
product-1.jpg
product-2.jpg
product-3.jpg
product-4.jpg
```

I have the following request (came from jQuery's `sortable`):

> action=save&photos=photo[]=4&photo[]=2&photo[]=3&photo[]=1

I've tried this:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['action'] == 'save') {
        parse_str($_POST['photos'], $photos);

        $id_new = 1;

        foreach($photos['photo'] as $id) {
            rename(dirname(__FILE__) . '/product-' . $id . '.jpg', dirname(__FILE__) . '/product-' . $id_new . '.jpg');

            $id_new++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But `rename` deletes some of the photos.

Comment: So what photos are deleted?

Comment: Привет, rename() cannot remove files, only overwrite existing files, maybe problem in that? try to rename them into some subfolder (or any other folder)  to check, is all files copied and renamed.

Comment: `product-1, product-2, product-3` are gone, when I run the script. `product-4` remains the same. Pretty weird!

Comment: print rename and check rename contains all images

Comment: `photos=photo[]=4` is a strange parameter

Comment: `print_r($photos['photo'])`, what do you see?

Comment: @u_mulder, it doesnt matter, because he did parse_str($_POST['photos'], $photos); and got normal array, but i agree with you, it is strange to pass parameters like that :)

Comment: Well, first I tried `print_r`, but apparently jQuery's `sortable` sends it that way, so I'll stick with `parse_str` for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have photos ids 4, 3, 2, 1 and you are renaming the files in the reverse order so:

1. if you rename 4 to 1 then 1 is overwritten and 4 disappear
2. if you rename 3 to 2 then 2 is overwritten and 3 disappear

That's why you remain with less files.

As @MVG1984 suggested in a comment you can rename those files into another folder like:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$tmpPath = $path . '/tmp';

mkdir($tmpPath);

$id_new = 1;
foreach($photos['photo'] as $id) {
    rename($path . '/product-' . $id . '.jpg', $tmpPath . '/product-' . $id_new . '.jpg');
    $id_new++;
}

for ($i = 1; $i < $id_new; $i++) {
    rename($tmpPath . '/product-' . $i . '.jpg', $path . '/product-' . $i . '.jpg');
}

rmdir($tmpPath);
```

Comment: That is exacty i've said :)

Comment: Actually, the ids are `1,2,3,4` and then I got `4,2,3,1`. I thought that this is the problem, but I was hoping for some advice how to fix it.

Comment: Edited the answer to give you a possible solution

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good idea with the temp folder. I tried with `.jpg.bak`, then `.jpg` but it didn't worked. Or maybe it didn't worked because of the image cache (now I realized that I have to restart my browser in order to see the changes).